# Declare two fields of a struct as mutually exclusive in CueLang?

Tags: cuelang

I want to ensure that my users only set one of two fields:

```yaml
rotations:
  - type: weekly
    time_restrictions:
      # Allow only ONE of the following fields:
      weekday_time_of_day: {...}
      time_of_day: [...]
```

I came across the [`OneOf` pattern on Cuetorials](https://cuetorials.com/patterns/fields/), but this does only seem to help when wanting to enforce a schema while writing *cue* files.

```
#OneOfTimeRestrictions: {time_of_day: [...string]} | {weekday_time_of_day: [...string]}

rotations: [{
    type:         *"weekly" | "daily"
    restrictions: #OneOfTimeRestrictions | {} // won't work, naturally, because nothing is "chosen" 
}]
```

(The values of the mutually exclusive fields are actually additional, more complex structs, not strings, in case that might matter - but for the sake of a shorter example I've omitted them.)

**However**, I'm trying to **vet YAML** instead.

The problem is that when defining this:

```
#OneOfTimeRestrictions: rotations: [{
    type:         *"weekly" | "daily"
    restrictions: {time_of_day: [...string]} | {weekday_time_of_day: [...string]}
}]
```

Both fields are acceptable, including when giving them at the same time.

Pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a cue expert but,
in CUE `{}` can be a closed or an open structure depending on the context.
`#A: {}` is a closed schema, meaning you can't add new field to it.
While `B:{}` is an open value where you can add new field to it.

```
#A:{}
a: a & {someKey: true} // will produce an error

B:{}
b: b & {someKey: true} // will pass

_C:{}
c: _C & {someKey: true} // will pass
```

(You can test it here: https://cuelang.org/play/?id=XigxaAJ1bcp#cue@export@cue)
(And read more about it here: https://cuetorials.com/deep-dives/closedness/)

So in your first CUE code example, the line `restrictions: #OneOfTimeRestrictions | {}` says `restrictions` must match either a closed schema with either a `weekday_time_of_day` or `time_of_day` field and nothing else or must match an unclosed `{}` which will match every non-null object.

In your second code example, you are saying `restictions` as to match to an open structure that has the `weekday_time_of_day` field or match to an open structure that has the `time_of_day` field. So, they are basically identical.

Try it like this

```
#OneOfTimeRestrictions: {time_of_day: [...string]} | {weekday_time_of_day: [...string]}


#Restrictions: {
    restrictionA: string
    restrictionB: bool
    // ...
    restrictionZ: bool

    #OneOfTimeRestrictions
}

rotations: [...{
    type: *"weekly" | "daily"
    restrictions: #Restrictions
}]
```

Or if you don't like the additional schema, like this

```
#OneOfTimeRestrictions: {time_of_day: [...string]} | {weekday_time_of_day: [...string]}

rotations: [...{
    type: *"weekly" | "daily"
    restrictions: {
        restrictionA:     string
        restrictionB:     bool
        // ...
        restrictionZ: bool
        
        #OneOfTimeRestrictions
    }
}]
```

But these solutions will make the objects in `relations` closed. So, you will have deliberately defined every additional restriction.
(I'm not certain why `restrictions` is close in my second example, but in my test it is closed).

If you need that the objects inside `relations` are open, you can use something like this:

```
rotations: [...{
    type: *"weekly" | "daily"
    restrictions: {

        time_of_day: [...string]
        weekday_time_of_day: [...string]

        _tr1: bool | *false
        _tr2: bool | *false

        if time_of_day == [] {
            _tr1: true
        }
        if weekday_time_of_day == [] {
            _tr2: true
        }

        _time_restiction_valid: true
        _time_restiction_valid: (_tr1 && !_tr2) || (!_tr1 && _tr2) // append '|| (!_tr1 && !_tr2)' if you want to allow that nither can be set
    }
}]
```

Comment: Ha! I wasn't fully aware of how closed/open structs work, it seems. That makes a lot of sense. I was wondering why my schema seemingly matches anything I throw at it.

Comment: In your second example, `restrictions` is closed because it embeds `#OneOfTimeRestrictions`, which is closed. See the [spec on embedding](https://cuelang.org/docs/references/spec/#embedding), specifically: "if an embedding resolves to a closed struct, the corresponding enclosing struct will also be closed"